# How to get an added row to bottom of the table after remote data is load in same table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
   getTableData function performs an `ajax` request to get data from the remote server and load this data into HTML table:

    getTableData(tableName, startRow, endRow, function() {
       alert("test");
       $(".logTable tr:last").after($addTableRow); // last line in this callback
    });

    getTableData(tName, sRow, eRow, callback)
    {
       CK.AddTableRow = $.get("getTableData.php", {tN: tName, sR: sRow, eR: eRow});
       buildLogTable(callback);
    }

    buildLogTable(callback)
    {
       CK.AddTableRow.done(tabledata)
       {
          // add the return tabledata to log table
          callback();
       }
     }
```

When I add the alert function, this `$addTableRow` row in the callback function above correctly gets added to the bottom of the table after the remote data is added to the table.

Here's the problem:

When I remove the alert function, this `$addTableRow` row gets added to the top of table before the remote data is added to the table.

Help:

I need this `$addTableRow` added to the bottom of the `table` after the remote data has been added.

Comment: You're going to have to post the ajax function as well, as getting the content below the added table relies on the callback from the ajax function, or just using `prepend` in the ajax callback instead etc.

Comment: I've added the ajax function part to better understand my problem...

Comment: I don't grok that code at all, but your callbacks aren't inside the `done` methods etc. from the ajax call, they are just called immediately ?

Comment: Good point that I forgot to mention, even placing the callback inside the done function, the same problem happens.

Comment: Maybe I have a different problem, like, I need to know when the data has finish loading in the table instead of knowing when the data has finish returning from the server?

Comment: Appending the data to the table is synchronous, so that happens when it happens, on the next line of javascript it's there.

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` ajax call is asynchronous. You need to keep the `callback` function inside `done`., after you have added remote data to the table.

```
buildLogTable(callback)
    {
       CK.AddTableRow.done(tabledata)
       {
          // add the return tabledata to log table
          callback();
       }

     }
```

While using `alert`, it might hold the execution until you press 'OK' on alert. Meanwhile the function `done` completes the work. So the row gets added at the end.

HTH.

Comment: What do you mean I need to keep the callback?

Comment: I pressed 'Save' by mistake, before finishing the answer. I have updated it now.

Comment: Let me verify your excellent point but I'm pretty sure I got the same results.

Comment: Your point is good one but I still get the same results, meaning the added row goes to the top and not to bottom after removing the alert function

Comment: How can I tell when the data has finish loading in the table not when the data has return?

Comment: `done` would be called after the ajax returns with data. Here you have to load the remote data to the table first. And at the end call the `callback`.

Comment: Also, how is it working for you to directly call the function as `callback()`. As far as I know we need `call` to do so. e.g. `callback.call()`